# dropdown list distinct value yii2

Tags: postgresql, yii2, dropdown

I tried to make a dropdown from my postgres database and the database is like this

```
| id_provinsi | id_waktu |  id_kbli |
|     1000    |   12007  |     A    |
|     1000    |   12007  |     A1   |
|     1000    |   12007  |     A2   |
|     1000    |   12008  |     A    |
|     1000    |   12008  |     A1   |
|     1000    |   12008  |     A2   |
|     1100    |   12007  |     A    |
|     1100    |   12007  |     A1   |
|     1100    |   12007  |     A2   |
|     1100    |   12008  |     A    |
|     1100    |   12008  |     A1   |
|     1100    |   12008  |     A2   |
```

and I want to get a dropdown that shows `id_waktu` like this

```
| 12007 |
| 12008 |
```

My code:

```
$pdrb=PdrbProv::find()->groupBy('id_waktu')->all();
$listData=ArrayHelper::map($pdrb,'id_provinsi','id_waktu');

echo $form->field($model, 'id_waktu')->dropDownList(
    $listData,
    ['prompt'=>'Select...']
    );
```

but I get the following error:

```
QLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "pdrb_prov.id_provinsi" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM "pdrb_prov" GROUP BY "id_waktu"
^
The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM "pdrb_prov" GROUP BY "id_waktu"
```

What am I supposed to do? Can anyone help? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these query

```
$pdrb = PdrbProv::find()
           ->select('id_provinsi, id_waktu')
           ->groupBy('id_waktu')
           ->all();
```

Comment: thanks. it work. but it seems i can't echo $pdrb. Any option how to do this

Comment: You can't echo . becasue it gives result as array. use  print_r()

Comment: so what should i do to make a dropdown list from it?

Comment: You can use [kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2] for these

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdrb = PdrbProv::find()->select(['id_provinsi','id_waktu'])->distinct()->all();
```

Comment: While this code may address the core of the question, please provide some context or explanation.